# How to get all dropdown selected item value and push to another oData in SAPui5?

Tags: sapui5

1. All dropdown selected item value getting from first oDATA and Second oDATA.
2. Once select or choose all dropdown 
   value item then 
   I want to push all 
   selected item value to third oDATA.(Eg: After click Append button)

Sample Screenshot Image Output Code below:

---

```
function() {

//get first dropdown box selected key from first odata

  var plant = sap.ui.getCore().byId("plant").getSelectedKey(); 
  if (plant != 0) {


    var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_M_EPM_BOM_SRV/";
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
    var filterList = [];
    var i;

    filterList.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, plant));
    // first dropdown box selected value filter to second odata key
    oModel.read("/MatCharFieldSet", {
          context: null,
          async: false,
          filters: filterList,
          urlParameters: {
            "$expand": "MatCharValuesSet"
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var res = data.results;
            var content = [];
            for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

              content.push(new sap.m.Label({
                text: res[i].DescrChar,
                name: res[i].FieldName
              }));
              var items = [];
              for (var j = 0; j < res[i].MatCharValuesSet.results.length; j++) {
                items.push(new sap.ui.core.Item({
                  text: res[i].MatCharValuesSet.results[j].FieldValue,
                  key: res[i].MatCharValuesSet.results[j].FieldValue
                }));

              }
              content.push(new sap.m.Select({
                items: items
              }));
            }
            fields = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({

              editable: true,
              layout: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleFormLayout.ResponsiveGridLayout,
              labelSpanL: 4,
              labelSpanM: 4,
              adjustLabelSpan: true,
              emptySpanL: 0,
              emptySpanM: 0,
              columnsL: 4,
              columnsM: 4,
              content: content

            });

            fields.placeAt("fields", "only");

          }
```

How to push all selected value item to another oDATA ?

SAMPLE SCREENSHOT

[image: SAMPLE SCREENSHOT]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var getAllSelectInstances = $(".sapMSlt").control(); 
getAllSelectInstances.forEach(function(oSelect){
  var getSelectedItem = oSelect.getSelectedItem();
  var getSelectedText = getSelectedItem ? getSelectedItem.getText() : null;
  Console.log("Selected Value : " + getSelectedText);
});
```